# mail() : Failed to connect to mailserver

Tags: php, smtp

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\dressoholic\register.php on line 50
```

As i already installed a SMTP server but still I donot get emails in my gmail account instead i got mails on microsoft outlook but why emails donot appearing on my gmail account

Comment: "*Failed to connect* to the SMTP server at 'localhost' on port 25" - error is what it is say. So then, why is the server not listening?

Comment: did you START the smtp server? just installing it doesn't do much... and then did you CONFIGURE IT as well?

Comment: yes i configure it, now the error msg donot appear it works fine but why the mails donot appear on my gmail account instead of it they appears at outlook application

Comment: Despite the fact that you have a php tag, there's nothing programming related about this question... if you're having issues with your mailserver, try serverfault, otherwise you need to at a minimum explain why you think the emails should go to your gmail account (also do not is two words unless you're talking about a doughnut... mmm... doughnuts...)

Comment: @Foon Just wondoring what will be your reaction if someone write cookie in stackoverflow ? may be you are like,.....mmmmm cookie......

Comment: somewhere I have a yummy recipe for Honey Toffee Twix Pistachio cookies

Comment: blow stackoverflow ! you belongs to zomato.com dude

Answer (score 0):

There could be couple of issues:

1. It sounds like your [SMTP server is not allowing relay](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html). Talk to your mail server admin and ask if they will open relay for your application's IP address.
2. Try to use a valid 'from' email address in mail function